# Basic time of the day analysis

Tags: time-series

Let's say you have this dataset:

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| Hour of the day | Page visits |
+-----------------+-------------+
|               1 |          12 |
|               2 |           7 |
|               3 |           7 |
|               4 |          10 |
|               5 |           9 |
|               6 |           9 |
|               7 |           8 |
|               8 |           7 |
|               9 |           9 |
|              10 |           7 |
|              11 |          12 |
|              12 |           5 |
|              13 |          14 |
|              14 |           9 |
|              15 |           7 |
|              16 |           8 |
|              17 |           9 |
|              18 |           9 |
|              19 |          10 |
|              20 |          11 |
|              21 |           8 |
|              22 |          10 |
|              23 |           8 |
|              24 |           7 |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

I just want to know which period that page visits are most likely to occur. **E.g.**: Page visits are most likely to occur from 10am to 2pm.

How do I analyse this dataset?

Comment: Without any smoothing or modelling, the answer is 13:00. Otherwise a single answer is unlikely given several ways to process the data, e.g. various weighted averages and/or sinusoids of varying complexity.

Comment: @NickCox I'm afraid a single hour as an answer will not do. I don't know a lot about sinusoids. The only thing I understand from your comment is... get the **Mode**. Can I use standard deviation and just look it up beside the mode (13:00) if they are within the normal distribution?

Comment: If you have criteria here for "will not do", what are your criteria for "will do"? I can't see that normal distributions or standard deviation have any relevance here. **No analysis makes sense unless it respects the fact that you have a circular scale, time of day.** There are many threads here on sinusoids.

Comment: You have to define 'period' first. As it stands, @NickCox is correct, the answer is 13. You can create a moving average of n hours and recompute, but the answer will depend on n

Comment: A moving average would be a good choice. I only heard of it in here but that's probably the best solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, a moving average of some kind may help. Here we see the results of smoothing with weights (1:2:1)/4 and (1:4:6:4:1)/16, otherwise known as binomial filters of length 3 (Hanning) and 5 (Hanning repeated).

A simple trick to wrap the smoothers round at the end of the day is to smooth on the data copied three-fold and then just to show results for the middle part.

[image]

The results are not especially clear-cut. There are essentially no details on the generating process given in the original post, but various peaks in visit times presumably mix times of leisure and/or visitors from different time zones.

As there appear to be perhaps 4 minor peaks, sinusoids don't seem likely to help further.

Comment: Nick, thanks for pointing this to a direction. It took me hours to try to figure out the things you mentioned.

I am trying to build a software specific for this application. It seems the only way to attain the range of peaks -- as per the stated example from the question -- is to be able to pinpoint the peaks. Is there a way to pinpoint the positive and negative peaks programmatically?

Comment: Identifying peaks and troughs is surely programmable by selecting values higher (lower) than their neighbours. Remember to wrap around and work on visits[24], visits[1], ..., visits[24], visits[1]. The bigger deal is how and how much to smooth before you do that.